# Keep losing IP with dhcpcd

Tags: networking, arch-linux, virtualbox, ip, dhcp

I have an Arch Linux install in a VirtualBox VM, and as I'm working all of a sudden, it will lose its dynamic IP address.

When this happens, if I check on the status of the `dhcpcd` service, it says it's running.

```
$ systemctl status dhcpcd.service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2013-09-28 20:10:32 EDT; 49min ago
 Main PID: 166 (dhcpcd)
```

I can try to restart the service, but it does not establish an IP.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

```
**No output is returned from the command*
```

I can set an address manually, and it will work for a while, but then it'll drop again after a few minutes.

```
$ sudo ifconfig enp0s3 10.0.0.109 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
$ sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.1
```

I can also run `dhcpcd` manually, and it will successfully get an IP address, but again it will drop after a few minutes.

```
$ sudo dhcpcd enp0s3
dhcpcd[2580]: sending commands to master dhcpcd process
```

I have tried disabling `dhcpcd.service` and using `dhcpcd@enp0s3.service`, but it has the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have another network manager running, do you?

Comment: @jasonwryan, no.

Comment: I'd use `dhclient` instead. I experienced lots of problems with `dhcpcd` on Gentoo lately. Probably they appeared after update, however it didn't work well until I changed the client app.

Comment: dhcpcd on arch linux behaves a bit differently from other distros. For example, it spawns its own wpa_supplicant, and it probably does something similar for wired connections. I would look carefully at the source, I believe there is an argument you can pass to dhcpcd to make it behave normally

Comment: Can you post the `dmesg | tail` output when this happens?

Comment: This post is old. I'm no longer using that VM. It's been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same problem and worked around it by installing an older version of `dhcpcd`. the latest version that seems to work is 5.6.8-1

Maybe try manually compiling the package? or disabling dhcpcd entirely and just configuring your VM ip statically.